# jQuery scroll to anchors (animation) prevents carousel data-slide from working

Tags: jquery

On single page web site (A) I have used jquery (B) to scroll from navigation links to section heads (anchors) and also Text link scroll back to top.
This script  however overrides the the carousel function (data-slide)( C ) . So carousel arrows scroll to top no long data-slide to next

How can I target the scroll to the specific nav links. and not to carousel action

(I have little experience with jQuery)

---

A) website
 http://www.cricketneckguard.com.au/

EXAMPLE html

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#features" rel="" id="anchor1" >FEATURES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" rel="" id="anchor2" >ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#test" rel="" id="anchor3">TESTING</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sales" rel="" id="anchor4" class="animate">PURCHASE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact" rel="" id="anchor5" >CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>

 <h2><span id="test"></span>Testing</h2>

<p><a href="#top">TOP <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></span></a></p>
```

B) jQuery used

```
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') 
        || location.hostname == this.hostname) {

        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
           if (target.length) {
             $('html,body').animate({
                 scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

C) carousel html

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a> <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i have for a scroll to top

the JS:

```html
  /* Back to top smooth scroll */
  $scrollTop.on('click', function (e) {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }, 1000)
  });
```

my HTML

```html
      <div id="scrollToTop" role="button" >        
        <span class="fa fa-caret-square-o-up"></span>
      </div>
```

As you can see, my selector (#scrollToTop) is an ID, as i'm only using this once per page. This isn't an A tag, but has the role as button for accessibility. If you stick with your A tag, give it an ID and extrapolate from there.

GL!

Comment: Thank you for your answer Mark. Unfortuneately I do not know how to add a class to scroll top to try this?

Comment: can you adjust the HTML, if not you could use jQuery .addclass.

Comment: Hi Mark I really am unable to get my head around this.  (I don't understand js well enough to code) BUT I have a thought ... If I delete the 'scroll top' jquery the Carousel buttons work So is there some way I Could disable the Scroll top function for the the carousel-control class? Sorry to be such a pain.